# what would be an extensible structure for node.js with native mongodb driver in Typescript

Tags: node.js, mongodb, data-structures, typescript, data-access-layer

using node.js with the native mongodb driver is there a way to enforce a schema/schemaless structure by using classes or interfaces with Typescript (ES6). For example, if we have a collection called users. and we do something along the lines of

```js
//Interface Library
interface INewUser {
  name: string,
  age: number,
  location: string
}

//DAL
function insertUser(data: INewUser, cb: MongoCallBack < InsertOneWriteOpResult > ) {

  //for best practices we would have an instance connected to db already
  //so we do not have to open a new connection on every request
  MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {

    //handle err first

    db.collection("users", function(err, col) {

      //handle err first

      col.insertOne(data, function(err, response: InsertOneWriteOpResult) {
        //MongoCallBack expects (MongoError, <T>) T = InsertOneWriteOpResult
        return cb(null, response)
      });

    });

  });
}


//api endpoint
app.post('/user', function(req, res) {
  //do some checks to make sure the req.body is valid -- i.e not empty no xss attacks..
  let newUser: INewUser = req.body;

  insertUser(newUser, function(err, res) {
    if (res.res.ok == 1) {
      res.json({
        success: true
      });
    }

  });
});




/*example data being posted to /user
{
  name: "test",
  age: 33,
  location: "NA"
} */
```

I'm looking to find some of the best styles/techniques that could be used to structure data flow throughout an application utilizing typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I have an application which is in production and works in a similar way that you described.

Though It's not `mongodb` and it uses an ORM `sequelize` with MySQL. Back in the past I've used mongoose, but this was not the requirement with the application I'm working on right now.

Nevertheless I use something similar :

```
// models/User.js
export interface UserAttributes {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    location: string;
}

interface UserInstance extends UserAttributes {
    id: number;
}
```

Then in my AJAX end-points I use [Joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi), for validating the schema

```
import { UserAttributes } from "../models/User";

const schema = Joi.object( {
    name : Joi.string().required(),
    age: Joi.string().required(),
    location: Joi.string().required()
} );

server.post("/user", function( req, res ) {

   const body = req.body; 

   Joi.validate( body, schema, function( errors ) {

       if ( !errors ) {
          const user : UserAttributes = req.body;
          db.User.create( user ).then( user => res.json( { user } ) );
       } else {
          // handle error logic
       }

   });

});
```

This has the benefit that you validate the model before you assign it to your interface. Making sure that you will always have a valid `user` after the AJAX call.